# Get a header with Python and convert in JSON (requests - urllib2 - json)

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, urllib2, python-requests

I’m trying to get the header from a website, encode it in JSON to write it to a file.
I’ve tried two different ways without success.

FIRST with urllib2 and json

```
import urllib2
import json
host = ("https://www.python.org/")
header = urllib2.urlopen(host).info()
json_header = json.dumps(header)
print json_header
```

in this way I get the error:

> TypeError:  is not
>   JSON serializable

So I try to bypass this issue by converting the object to a string -> json_header = str(header) 
In this way I can json_header = json.dumps(header) but the output it’s weird:

> "Date: Wed, 02 Jul 2014 13:33:37 GMT\r\nServer: nginx\r\nContent-Type:
>   text/html; charset=utf-8\r\nX-Frame-Options:
>   SAMEORIGIN\r\nContent-Length: 45682\r\nAccept-Ranges: bytes\r\nVia:
>   1.1 varnish\r\nAge: 1263\r\nX-Served-By: cache-fra1220-FRA\r\nX-Cache: HIT\r\nX-Cache-Hits: 2\r\nVary: Cookie\r\nStrict-Transport-Security:
>   max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains\r\nConnection: close\r\n"

SECOND with requests

```
import requests
r = requests.get(“https://www.python.org/”)
rh = r.headers
print rh
```

> {'content-length': '45682', 'via': '1.1 varnish', 'x-cache': 'HIT',
>   'accept-ranges': 'bytes', 'strict-transport-security':
>   'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains', 'vary': 'Cookie', 'server':
>   'nginx', 'x-served-by': 'cache-fra1226-FRA', 'x-cache-hits': '14',
>   'date': 'Wed, 02 Jul 2014 13:39:33 GMT', 'x-frame-options':
>   'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'age':
>   '1619'}

In this way the output is more JSON like but still not OK (see the ‘ ‘ instead of “ “ and other stuff like the = and ;).
Evidently there’s something (or a lot) I’m not doing in the right way.
I’ve tried to read the documentation of the modules but I can’t understand how to solve this problem.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are more than a couple ways to encode headers as `JSON`, but my first thought would be to convert the `headers` attribute to an actual dictionary instead of accessing it as `requests.structures.CaseInsensitiveDict`

```
import requests, json
r = requests.get("https://www.python.org/")
rh = json.dumps(r.headers.__dict__['_store'])
print rh
```

> {'content-length': ('content-length', '45474'), 'via': ('via', '1.1
>   varnish'), 'x-cache': ('x-cache', 'HIT'), 'accept-ranges':
>   ('accept-ranges', 'bytes'), 'strict-transport-security':
>   ('strict-transport-security', 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains'),
>   'vary': ('vary', 'Cookie'), 'server': ('server', 'nginx'),
>   'x-served-by': ('x-served-by', 'cache-iad2132-IAD'), 'x-cache-hits':
>   ('x-cache-hits', '1'), 'date': ('date', 'Wed, 02 Jul 2014 14:13:37
>   GMT'), 'x-frame-options': ('x-frame-options', 'SAMEORIGIN'),
>   'content-type': ('content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'), 'age':
>   ('age', '1483')}

Depending on exactly what you want on the headers you can specifically access them after this, but this will give you all the information contained in the headers, if in a slightly different format.

If you prefer a different format, you can also convert your headers to a dictionary:

```
import requests, json
r = requests.get("https://www.python.org/")
print json.dumps(dict(r.headers))
```

> {"content-length": "45682", "via": "1.1 varnish", "x-cache": "HIT",
>   "accept-ranges": "bytes", "strict-transport-security":
>   "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains", "vary": "Cookie", "server":
>   "nginx", "x-served-by": "cache-at50-ATL", "x-cache-hits": "5", "date":
>   "Wed, 02 Jul 2014 14:08:15 GMT", "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
>   "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8", "age": "951"}

Comment: Thank you very much @Slater Tyranus. Your second method it's exactly what I was looking for. Just one question out of curiosity. Reading the output of your first method I see that keys and values are inside ' '. Why json.dumps does that in that case? Should a valid JSON format have values inside " "?

Answer (score 10):

If you are only interested in the header, make a `head` request. convert the `CaseInsensitiveDict` in a `dict` object and then convert it to `json`.

```
import requests
import json
r = requests.head('https://www.python.org/')
rh = dict(r.headers)
json.dumps(rh)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://www.python.org/')
rh = r.headers

print json.dumps( dict(rh) ) # use dict()
```

result:

> {"content-length": "45682", "via": "1.1 varnish", "x-cache": "HIT", "accept-ranges": "bytes", "strict-transport-security": "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains", "vary": "Cookie", "server": "nginx", "x-served-by": "cache-fra1224-FRA", "x-cache-hits": "5", "date": "Wed, 02 Jul 2014 14:08:04 GMT", "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN", "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8", "age": "3329"}

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I stumbled across it when trying to put together a quick and dirty Python `curl`-esque URL getter.  I kept getting an error:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'CaseInsensitiveDict' is not JSON serializable
```

The above solutions are good if need to output a JSON string immediately, but in my case I needed to return a python dictionary of the headers, and I wanted to normalize the capitalization to make all keys lowercase.

My solution was to use a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
import requests

response = requests.head('https://www.python.org/')

my_dict = {
   'body': response.text,
   'http_status_code': response.status_code,
   'headers': {k.lower(): v for (k, v) in response.headers.items()}
}
```