# how to write r.headers from different urls into one json?

Tags: json, python-requests

I would like to crawl several urls, while using the requests library in python. I am scrutinizing the GET requests as well as the response headers. However, when crawling and getting the data from different urls  I am facing the problem, that I don't know all 'key:values', which are coming in. Thus writing those data to a valid csv file is not really possible, in my point of view. Therefore I want to write the data into a json file.

The problem is similar to the following thread from 2014, but not the same:
[Get a header with Python and convert in JSON (requests - urllib2 - json)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533018/get-a-header-with-python-and-convert-in-json-requests-urllib2-json)

```py
import requests, json

urls = ['http://www.example.com/', 'http://github.com']

with open('test.json', 'w') as f:

    for url in urls:
        r = requests.get(url)
        rh = r.headers
        f.write(json.dumps(dict(rh), sort_keys=True, separators=(',', ':'), indent=4))
```

I expect a json file, with the headers for each URL. I get a Json file with those data, but my IDE (PyCHarm) is showing an Error, which states out that
JSON standard allows only one top-level value. I have read the documentation:https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#repeated-names-within-an-object; but did not get it. Any hint would be appreciated.
EDIT: The only thing which is missing in the outcome is another comma. But where do I enter it and what command do I need for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add it to an array and then finally do the json dump to a file. This will work.

```
urls = ['http://www.example.com/', 'http://github.com']
headers = []

for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url)
    header_dict = dict(r.headers)
    header_dict['source_url'] = url
    headers.append(header_dict)

with open('test.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(headers, f, sort_keys=True, separators=(',', ':'), indent=4)
```

You still can write it to a csv:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(headers)
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```